# Grouped GridView Scroll To One Group

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a GridView with SemanticZoom, that displays grouped data. It works well.
But I want to know how to scroll to specified group with code. Just like one click on the Zoomed Out View.
I searched and tried,but cann't find the answer.
the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote this article on my blog about this issue. Basicly I provide two 'views' of the items, one of them in a GridView and other in a FlipView.

When user zoom in a GridView Item the SemanticZoom change to FlipView and set as current item the item selected in GridView.

The article is in spanish, my native language, I hope this is not a big problem for you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juank/archive/2012/11/05/semanticzoom-como-hacer-zoom-item-especifico-winrt-csharp.aspx

Make Zoom in a FlipView is not a trivial issue, but in the article I fix this issue using a SemanticViewHost class created by another Microsoft MVP: Luis Guerrero in this article: http://luisguerrero.net/blog/2012/08/11/usando-un-contentcontrol-como-hijo-de-un-control-semanticzoom-en-xamlc-de-windows-8/